# É possível substituir o controle do alarme do meu carro por um aplicativo?

Tags: android, mobile

Estou começando um projeto pessoal de automação veicular.

No primeiro momento vou utilizar os recursos nativos de meu SmartPhone, para não precisar implementar nenhum circuito no carro a priori.

Tenho um Galaxy S4, e um carro com alarme Pósitron. Gostaria de criar um aplicativo que tivesse os mesmos botões do meu chaveiro, como: ativa e desativar o alarme mais o auxiliar.

### Perguntas:

É possível fazer essa implementação?
**Se sim** como mandar uma frequência codificada que "imita" a frequência e o sinal  emitida pelo controle do meu alarme?

Comment: msantiago, você não tá querendo montar um app pra roubar carro não? huaehuhua

Comment: É possível, mas o problema é de hardware, e não de programação, pois a solução envolve fazer um transmissor para adicionar ao aparelho (seja pela saida de áudio, ou usb). Talvez o melhor caminho fosse resolver essa parte, e depois trazer o problema da programação para o SOpt.

Comment: Então, respondi que não é possível, dada as condições oferecidas pelo usuário, aonde o hardware é o S4.

Comment: Pela discussão e respostas (afinal, eu não entendo nada do assunto), eu concordo com o @Bacco no fato de que na formulação atual o problema é mais de hardware do que de software. Mas, ainda assim, não vale a pena manter a pergunta aqui apenas para explicitar esse conhecimento? Achei potencialmente útil.

Comment: Mas, se alguém se sentir tentando a continuar essa discussão em particular, creio que seja mais vantajoso abrir uma questão no meta. :)

Comment: Eu não tinha votado para fechar quando a pergunta foi feita para dar tempo de orientarem o OP nos comentários (e no fim saiu até uma resposta). Isto já resolvido, estou "puxando a fila" do fora de escopo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não é possível, pois as ondas eletromagnéticas emitidas pelos alarmes são codificadas em frequências muito baixas(+- 430Mhz) em relação a um smartphone, não seria possível reproduzir este tipo de onda através de um aparelho celular sem hardware específico para emitir e codificar adequadamente esta onda.

**Detalhe:** Se um criminoso determinado realmente quiser entrar no seu carro, pode usar um agarrador de código(vulgo chapolin) para fazer uma cópia da sua "chave". Um agarrador de código é um receptor de rádio sensível ao sinal do seu transmissor. Ele recebe o código e o registra. Se o ladrão interceptar o seu "código para desativar", pode programar outro transmissor para imitar exatamente o seu sinal único e pessoal. Com esta chave copiada, o ladrão pode "enganar" o seu sistema de alarme na próxima vez que você deixar o carro sozinho.

Para resolver esse problema, os sistemas de alarme avançados estabelecem uma nova série de códigos cada vez que você ativa o alarme. Usando algoritmos de código rotativo, o receptor encripta o novo código de desativação e o envia ao transmissor. Uma vez que o transmissor só usa o código uma vez, qualquer informação interceptada não tem valor.

A menos que você consiga a forma de utilizar este algorítimo de código rotativo, não é possível reproduzir o sinal emitido.

http://carros.hsw.uol.com.br/alarmes-dos-carros.htm

Sobre o chapolin, recomendo ler, até para quem possui carro com alarme!!
http://g1.globo.com/fantastico/noticia/2014/04/aparelho-que-bloqueia-travamento-de-carros-e-nova-arma-dos-bandidos.html

Comment: Verdade, são Mhz, porém me referi a ser muito baixa em comparação com um smartphone como o S4.